# Is osteoid an uncalcified substance?

Tags: proteins, enzymes, bone-biology

I recently learned about Osteoid (the substance secreted by osteoblasts during intramembranous ossification), and I read that it was an "unmineralized organic component of bone."

Now, does this mean that Osteoid is un-*calcified*?? I don't know if I can equate unmineralized with uncalcified but I just wanted to make sure.